# How to do a Logical operation between a boolean variable and Function with integers as arguments in Golang

Tags: function, go, boolean, logical-operators

I want to how to do the logical operation "OR" between a Boolean variable and Function call

```
func Move(x int, y int, m int) int{

if IsvisitedNode(x,y){
var  possiblemove bool
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x+2, y+1, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x+2, y-1, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x-2, y+1, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x-2, y-1, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x+1, y+2, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x+1, y-2, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x-1, y+2, m+1)
 possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x-1, y-2, m+1)

if possiblemove == true {
 fmt.Println(x,y)

return true
}else{

visithistory[p] && visithistory[q] = false
        return false

        }
        }
        return 1
        }
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I am getting this error: invalid operation: possiblemove || Move(x + 2, y + 1, m + 1) (mismatched types bool and int) which is obvious but I cant find a solution HELP!!!

Comment: Of course you cannot to OR between int and bool. The question is: What do you want to achieve? What do you think `possiblemove || Move( x+1, y-2, m+1)` should be?

Comment: Through this I'm trying to find the knights tour solution in go lang through this https://play.golang.org/p/VUPD4Nv-If ,

Comment: Make function Move return a bool, not an int.

Comment: Im getting this,Index out of range error @Daniel Wisehart

Comment: @Manu: check the index values you're using. That's a separate problem entirely.

Comment: @JimB I didnt understand, what you meant.

Comment: @Manu: what part don't you understand? Do you understand what the "index out of range" panic means? https://play.golang.org/p/mdoie-efG4? Check the values you're using to index your slices or arrays.

Comment: I understood from your example what index out of range is but I cant understand Why am I getting this error in my code,https://play.golang.org/p/lqAYUCKYq_  @JimB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to evaluate 0 as false and any other number as true you could do:

```
possiblemove = possiblemove || Move( x+2, y+1, m+1) != 0
```

Comment: Im getting a index out of range error.https://play.golang.org/p/0CwZEFZ3xV  @jussius